# How to get new token and expiry date after calling extendAccessToTokenIfNeeded (this, null)?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I use Facebook's Android SDK but Facebook is deprecating the offline_access permission from 1st of May 2012. My android app uses offline_access so I am trying to update.  [In Step 8 of the Android tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token) we are told to use the following code to extend the access token...

```
public void onResume() {    
        super.onResume();
        facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
```

Assuming 24 hours between calls, the access token should be updated... but how do we then get that updated token so that it can be saved to SharedPreferences?  I have some code below that ***I think will work but I am not sure!***

The trouble is that if Facebook only allows token extending once every 24 hours I must wait 24 hours to see if the if facebook.getAccessExpires() works as expected!  If the code below does not work I must wait another 24 hours before trying something else.  This makes a very slow testing environment!

I hope the code below will work but does anyone already know the answer to this question?

```
facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

Date expiryDate = new Date(facebook.getAccessExpires());
Toast.makeText(this, "Access token is " + sdf.format(expiryDate),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//If calling facebook.getAccessToken() and facebook.getAccessExpires() works I will then save to SharedPreferences
```